# Using MQTT to transfer data to android

Tags: android, mqtt

I have a device that I have set up to transmit data it collects via MQTT. Now I need to allow Android to receive that data to display it. Where can I find an easy tutorial to follow to do this?

At the moment, I am showing the data through a webservice which pulls from MongoDB. I don't want to do this method because it is very expensive.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial/guide is off topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your question has three sides, you should follow each one individually:

The first one is sending the data from your device. You can use an mqtt client library (such as Paho) to publish your messages (depending on the programming language you are using).

The second part is setting up an mqtt broker that relays messages to the destination. (e.g. see http://www.hascode.com/2016/06/playing-around-with-mqtt-and-java-with-moquette-and-eclipse-paho/ which uses Moquette. It also contains a sample mqtt publisher using Java as well. The other option is using Mosquito mqtt broker).

And finally, an android application that subscribes to the same topic as the one sending the messages and receives them (You can use Paho client for this one too).

Search for each one of those and you will be able to build the system.